# "Overloading" subtraction for Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For all you Numpy wizards out there, I have a very specific task that I'm not sure how to approach.

I have a matrix calculation that I'm going to need to perform a huge number of times and so I want to rely on Numpy for as much optimization as I can. However, I need a couple little behavior quirks that aren't how Numpy normally operates and I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish them, either by some overloading or subclassing of Numpy functions, or performing an equivalent calculation using default behaviors that I might have missed.

**Problem and Desired Behavior**

I have two matrices. One is a 2D matrix, the other is 3D and essentially a sequence of matrices of the first type. For the 2D matrices the number of rows is fixed, but the number of columns is dynamic. They will look something like

```
[ 1 N N 4 N
  N 2 N N N
  ...
  N N 3 N N
  N N N N 5 ]
```

where N is some null value (I'll come back to that).

I need to perform subtraction on a row-by-row basis between the 2D matrix and the 2D slices of the 3D matrix. Easy enough to accomplish under normal circumstances with np.subtract. However, there are some complications that arise from this particular problem:

**1) The null value**

I need some way of storing an "empty" value. Normally I could just use 0, which in this case would capture my desired behavior for (number - Null) and (Null - number). However, I need some way of distinguishing (Null - Null) from the case where (number - number) = 0.

I've considered using some arbitrarily large, asymmetric value for Null, e.g. 1000 and -1000 respectively for the left and right matrices, which does allow me to recover the necessary information later, but is horribly inelegant and adds a lot of processing later that I don't want to expense.

**2) Variable row width**

The row dimension of the two matrices may not match. In this case, it can be assumed that the smaller of the two is padded at the end with Null values. I could pre-size all of them to the maximimum necessary dimension, but these are very sparse and I have *a lot* of them. I'd very much prefer some way of handling the dimensional difference at calculation time, if that's possible.

If anyone has any suggestions on efficiently accomplishing the desired effect, please shout them out, and let me know if anything is unclear. I've tried to be as concrete as I can but I am no Matrix Mage and so some things may not come across as well as I intended.

Comment: You could look into using [sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html). That would help reduce the memory taken up by your calculations and the arrays, plus would make number 2 easier if you have to pre-size them.

Comment: Don't start fancy - write a function that subtracts two rows.  Try alternatives - padded arrays, arrays of different length, lists, 'sparse lists' (look at the `scipy.sparse.lil` format.